# "Catch-all" rule for faces in theme definition

Tags: faces, themes

I am writing my own custom Emacs theme and I would like to express "if a face isn't explicitly listed above, don't color it".  Many modes have their own custom faces (e.g., Tuareg or Erlang mode) and I would rather not have to laboriously assign colors to every single one.